# How can I add a new field to my matrix visualization in PowerBi?

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, report, visualization

[image: This is what my matrix table looks like right now]

For context, I am building a table to show my company how many machines are not being serviced properly in each Year and Month respectively. The checking of whether or not it is done properly is by checking whether or not spare parts have been changed, once changed, in the column `[Need to follow up]` will have an output of "No" at the corresponding Spare Parts row, and I checked whether or not this machine has been fully serviced (means all of their required spare parts must have been changed) and hence all the rows should return No, and if a Yes is found, that machine's serial number is immediately marked as Incomplete in my new calculated column, `[Complete?]`,

#WO is based on a column in my table, `[Install Base]` it is the number of machines there are and for this matrix, I placed it under Values and Distinct Count it.
Complete and Incomplete are both measures that is based on my calculated column `[Complete?]`.

Here is the code,

```
# Incomplete change = 
VAR countYes = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('PM Checklist vs Last SP Used'[Install Base]),
    'PM Checklist vs Last SP Used'[Complete?] = "Incomplete")

RETURN
IF(countYes = BLANK(), 0, countNo)
```

```
# Complete change = 
VAR countNo = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('PM Checklist vs Last SP Used'[Install Base]),
    'PM Checklist vs Last SP Used'[Complete?] = "Complete")

RETURN
IF(countNo = BLANK(), 0, countNo)
```

`[Complete?]` is a calculated column, here is the code:

```
Complete? =
VAR currIB = 'PM Checklist vs Last SP Used'[Install Base]
VAR HasYes =
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(
            FILTER(
                'PM Checklist vs Last SP Used',
                'PM Checklist vs Last SP Used'[Need to change (w 90 days allowance)] = "Yes" &&
                [PM Update in CRM] = "Yes" &&
                [PM Material Type] = "PM SP" &&
                [PM Mandatory to Change] = "Yes"
            )
        ),
        ALLEXCEPT('PM Checklist vs Last SP Used', 'PM Checklist vs Last SP Used'[Install Base])
    )
 
RETURN IF(HasYes >0, "Incomplete", "Complete")
```

This table returns correct values for now and I want to take it a notch further by showing what are the spare parts and the count of them that are not changed for each model.

If I drag the `[Product]` column into my matrix row and expand, the values are very wrong, hence I am not sure how I should go about this as of right now

[image: After adding Products into my rows]

For instance, the model BM1060c had 5 machines that underwent servicing in December 2023, and out of the 5, 0 was serviced completely and 5 was incomplete. Below the header contains the serial of the spare parts that should have been changed, and the values all reflect 5, which don't match my dataset when I cross check, it should be returning me the number of rows that `[Complete?] = Incomplete` for each product serial and returning the count

Any help would be appreciated as I am relatively new to PowerBI. Thanks!

Comment: Adding the new field to the matrix isn't the issue - the issue is how are the values being calculated. `#WO`, `Complete`, `Incomplete` - where are these three coming from? Column or Measure? Update your question to include any DAX expressions used for these three values, as well as what your data model looks like (for example, is this matrix based on the one data table or several?).

Comment: I have edited my question, please let me know if I have left anything out! Thank you so much for your help

Comment: It helps, though we need to see your data model (relevant tables and their relationships). Are you able to share a sample PBIX (share a link to One Drive, Google Drive, Drop Box etc...)